# I can not set an icon in a Button using Vaadin plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, vaadin

I m using Vaadin plugin 6.8 in Eclipse Juno under Win 7. I installed Apache 7 (zip version) and configured with Eclipse. I created a Vaadin project and just added these lines:

```
Button b = new Button("Miboton"); // create button
b.setIcon(new ThemeResource("user.png")); // set image to button
mainWindow.addComponent(b);//add button to main window
```

But when I run the project the image is not desplayed because (I suposse) apache cant find the relative path to the image. I put the image in every posible directory: WEB-INF, src, under the package, etc. But still no desplayed properly. I also tried making a foo.war file and deploying it in Apache directly but that neither worked. Any guess?!?! Thanks in advance!

And image of eclipse code and the result is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35638831/error.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to serve up the images from the VAADIN directory.  See the Book of Vaadin concerning [Themes](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) and [Resources](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html)

Comment: Thanks! It works! I also recomend to read chapter 7 of the Book of Vaadin. I resolve the problem making a new theme and extends it from the reindeer theme. Thanks again!